# Delete all files older than X days and all empty folder (linux/bash)

Tags: bash, find, gnu

I am deleting all files recursively with:

```
$ find . -type f -name "*.*" -daystart -mtime +100 -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

Followed by all empty folders with:

```
$ find . -type d -empty -delete
```

since I don't want to delete folders older than e.g. 100 days that might contain files younger than 100 days.

But is there a more clean way to do this or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: This is very dangerous. Files in (for example) `~/.ssh` (including `~/.ssh` itself) will be removed if you run this from your home directory, unless you regenerate your keys frequently.

Answer (score 1):

combine both commands into one;

```
find /some/path -depth \( \( -type f -daystart -mtime +100 \) -o -type d -empty \) -ls
```

- this is to deleting all the regular files older than 100days from the beginning of today to of their last modification time.
- plus all empty directories.

replace `-ls` with `-delete` after you confirmed what files/directories are going to be deleted and ***be careful and aware what and from which path you are deleting!!***

Comment: You need `-depth` when testing without `-delete`

Comment: @roaima yes, you are right, edited, thanks